# How do I always add a value from my data to serializer.errors (DRF)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to pass an integer field called Id into a serializer, and always add it to serializer.errors (if there are any. For example:

```py
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # magical way to take Id in and add it to errors 

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = "__all__"
```

Then, if there are any errors, they should look like:

```json
{"error": "error message", "Id": 1}
```

I can't just add the field to serializer.errors after serializer.is_valid() runs, because I also want to use `many=True` on my serializer.

Also, it turns out that you can't add a dictionary as an error message, for example:

```py
validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Item.objects.all(),
                fields=["org", "item_name"],
                message={"cool":"dictionary"}, #this doesn't work :(
            )
        ]
```

And no, I can't store the Id in the model itself. Due to the way my frontend is using this API, the Id will change on most API calls.